# SQL - Remove trailing " where it exists in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table that will be receiving new data daily.  At times, the data in 3 of the 10 columns contains a trailing double quote (").  Is there an easy way to remove that final quote where it exists?  Whatever the query or procedure is, I will be running it from either python or vba, depending on where this project goes in the next 2 weeks - but I think if I can get it to work from Microsoft SQL Server Mgmt Studio, I'll be able to modify for either one.

Comment: This should probably be done as part of the process that inserts the data into the tables. How does the data get into the tables?

Comment: Jacob - thanks - the data is attached to an email (.csv) which is converted to a .txt and bulk uploaded.  It looks like the data that gets the extra set of quotation marks are the ones that contain quotation marks within the strings.  
For example, in the source, I see
KEYWORDS:"machine" WITHIN TOPIC:CLOAN 
which after upload becomes
"KEYWORDS:""machine"" WITHIN TOPIC:CLOAN"

I can strip everything out but that last quotation mark.  But if maybe there is a better way to insert the data, I'm happy to give that a shot too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE table
SET column = left(column,length(column)-1)
WHERE column like '%"'
```

Comment: Wiimm... thank you!  I changed length to len - that did it!!!!!!!!!!!!!